# Persist if checkbox is clicked through postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a checkbox that is set to "false" as default in the aspx. Then there is a function that determines whether it is true or false, the problem is that when on the page there is a textbox and this textbox has a TextChange Event on it, when i type something in the textbox and then go to the checkbox which at this time is visible the first time i click the whole page postbacks and resets the checkbox to unchecked.. then i need to click it again and then it sticks.. what can I do to make it stick at the first click?

Can I use some javascript for this or what do you think my options are?

```
 protected void myTextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowCheckBox(true);
    }

  private void ShowCheckBox(bool ckVal)
   {
      myCheckBox.Visible = ckVal;
   }
```

Comment: If you are setting the checkbox to checked in your code-behind, this should remain checked after postback, unless there are issues with viewstate etc?

Comment: Are you perhaps setting the 'default' checked value to false in code-behind?

Comment: Yes I do, in a if and else stament but i have a break point there and it never passes through that line

Comment: Can you show us the original code (the if/else statement you mentioned in your comment) where you check the `CheckBox`?

Comment: Are you including `if (!IsPostBack)` when you initialize your check box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why not add the textbox inside an update panel something like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="test">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TEXTBOX" runat="server" Visible="true" AutoPostBack="true"
            OnTextChanged="checkUser" >Page Name</asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TEXTBOX" EventName="TextChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 5):

My best guess is that your check box initialization (what sets Checked to false) runs on every postback. E.g. change this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myCheckBox.Checked = false;
}
```

to this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        myCheckBox.Checked = false;
}
```

However, we'll need to see some more code before we can effectively assist you. Part of the issue might be that ViewState is not persisted when the control is not Visible. If all that you want to do is show/hide it, use javascript as others have suggested.

Here's an example with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#myTextBox").change(function() {
    $("#myCheckBox").show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If i was you,i would write some clode in client side to show the check box or hide it,
writting suck code in server side is not good and needs extra roundtrip 
also you can use an updatepanel  to do that

Answer (score 3):

Checkbox, if `.Visible = false` is not rendered to the client. So when postback happens the default value of "false" is what it's set to.

You can render control all the time and toggle visibility via CSS so the checkbox is always part of the control tree and its ViewState is persisted.

`style="display:none"` and `style="display:inline"`

Answer (score 0):

You did not post the whole code so I am just going to guess. Try setting the AutoPostBack property for the textbox to false and see if that fixes it.

If that does not do it please post your code or a full sample code that reproduces the problem.